# Scala Macro Annotation: "scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: not found: value x"

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have a simple class that declares two variables.

```
class A {
    val x = 10
    @macro var y = x
}
```

Macro needs to infer type of variable x and print it.

```
val q"var $_ = $value" = annottees.head.tree
val typedTree = c.typecheck(value) // TypecheckException: not found: value x
println(typedTree.tpe)
```

But typecheck throws exception `TypecheckException` because it can't find value `x`. It seems that `x` doesn't get into the scope of macro and it can't see `x` variable and typecheck it.

So, how to infer rhs type of var declaration in macro annotation ?